# Radio button returning the previous value in ngchange

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I am trying to create a directive for a radio input with values. These values will be passed from a directive. I also want to update a value in the controller when the radio button is changed. Here is what I came up with...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = 1;
  $scope.values = [
    1,2,3,4
    ];
  $scope.update=function(){
    console.log("the value is "+ $scope.selected)
  }
})
.directive('jgRadio', function() {
    return {
      restrict:"E",
      scope:{
        values:"=",
        selected:"=",
        update:"&"
      },
      template: '<input ng-repeat="item in values" type="radio" value="{{item}}" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-change="update()"></input>'
    };
  });
```

But the console log outputs the previously selected ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SoFRWVGtYRAfaVZWBZii))

can someone see what I am missing?

Comment: Not yet took the weekend off :-) I'll let you know

Answer (score 3):

Typical case of child scope inheritance issue, i suppose. Change your model binding to an object holding selected value and bind the object as two way binding:-

```
$scope.selected = {value: 1};
```

and from your directive remove the ugly `$parent` @ `$parent.selected` to `selected.value`

```
 <input ng-repeat="item in values" type="radio" ng-value="item" ng-model="selected.value" ng-change="update()"></input>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aitDbF?p=preview)**

The reason is that, after ng-change is run, the digest cycle needs to run to update the value of 2 way binding on the consumer of the directive. And digest cycle will run only after the evaluation of `ng-change` function is completed. So in your function 2-way bound variable's value is not yet updated on the parent scope when you do `console.log($scope.selected)` inside the parent controller. So you see console.log showing previous value on the scope and binding still gets updated after the digest cycle. When you bind and object instead of primitive to the 2-way binding both the 2-way bound scope variable and parent controller scope variable points to the same object reference and the change is reflected immediately, also prefer using [`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) against `value={{item}}` especially when you deal with radio inputs.

> Binds the given expression to the value of input[select] or input[radio], so that when the element is selected, the ngModel of that element is set to the bound value.

Comment: Just updated my answer with explanation.. :) question is more interesting than i previously thought..

Comment: Another interesting sidenote is if I add an apply before it throws an error and then works. So this answer helps a big but is the answer with regard to primitives you can't do anything but set an arbitrary timeout?

Comment: @Jackie It is the basics of how 2 way binding works and how digest cycle works (there is no magic that set the value on the isolated scope to the 2 way bound parent scope, it needs digest cycle to be run). You dont do any apply :) when you are in angular context. That is what the last paragraph explains. I wouldn't use timeout either for this. You could probably delay your processing by pushing into async queue by using `scope.$evalAsync`

Comment: Well there isanother way could do is to pass the value of current selected through the bound function and get it atthe parent.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FcivQTotZAyjh5EvFNRr

```
  $scope.update=function(){
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log("the value is "+ $scope.selected);
    })
  }
```